# I cant get ordered by id items when using distinct

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm braking my head over this and tried a lot of version but it's just not working for me 
I need to get a distinct ordered by id. I understand that after distinct I need to order my list, but i can't get any identifier. And the results I'm getting has no logical order (1,2, 8, 4, 5,6,9). Please advise me .

```
public class TakeAway
{
    public int TakeAwayId { get; set; }
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public virtual Genre genre { get; set; }
}

public class Genre
{
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public string GenreName { get; set; }
    public List<TakeAway> TakeAwys { get; set; }

}

var allDishGenre = 
    db.TaKeAways.Select(x => x.genre.GenreName).Distinct().OrderBy(g => g).ToList();
ViewBag.GenreTab = allDishGenre;
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
db.TaKeAways.Select(x => x.genre.GenreName).Distinct()
```

returns a distinct list of names (Strings), which do not have any identifiers. You need:

```
db.TakeAways
  .GroupBy(ta => ta.genre.GenreName)
  .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
  .OrderBy(ta => ta.TakeAwayId)
  .ToList()
```

Comment: thank u :The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.,FirstOrDefault()=System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.TakeAway_338CBCBCDACFFD7622FBC96D51CB597842A9F4888AC8E06902E32E5B2239330C as result

Comment: Thank u , as I wrote using FirstOrDefault gives me this wird results System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.TakeAway_338CBCBCDACFFD7622FBC96D51CB597842A9F4888AC8E06902E32E5B2239330C